# Modify section header in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, driver, sectionheader

I am having a Windows driver based solution and working on Visual Studio 2012. I want to modify section the permission flag of section header. I tried to do it with properties->linker but it did not modify the section header when i browser section header using CFF explorer.

I want to remove the write permission from INIT section header(needed for Win10). Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround for this. We can remove the "/driver" option from linked and then change the section header value in linker option from "init,d" to init,RE!W . Worked as expected for me.